# Extracting node values using XPath

Tags: php, xpath, html-parsing

There is a section of amazon.com from which I want to extract the data (node value only, not the link) for each item.

The value I'm looking for is inside  and `<span class="narrowValue">`

```
<ul data-typeid="n" id="ref_1000">
    <li style="margin-left: -18px">
        <a href="/s/ref=sr_ex_n_0?rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Ahow+to+grow+tomatoes&amp;sort=salesrank&amp;keywords=how+to+grow+tomatoes&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1327603358">
            <span class="expand">Any Department</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li style="margin-left: 8px">
        <strong>Books</strong>
    </li>
    <li style="margin-left: 6px">
        <a href="/s/ref=sr_nr_n_0?rh=k%3Ahow+to+grow+tomatoes%2Cn%3A283155%2Cp_n_feature_browse-bin%3A618073011%2Cn%3A%211000%2Cn%3A48&amp;bbn=1000&amp;sort=salesrank&amp;keywords=how+to+grow+tomatoes&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1327603358&amp;rnid=1000">
            <span class="refinementLink">Crafts, Hobbies & Home</span><span class="narrowValue">(19)</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li style="margin-left: 6px">
       <a href="/s/ref=sr_nr_n_1?rh=k%3Ahow+to+grow+tomatoes%2Cn%3A283155%2Cp_n_feature_browse-bin%3A618073011%2Cn%3A%211000%2Cn%3A10&amp;bbn=1000&amp;sort=salesrank&amp;keywords=how+to+grow+tomatoes&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1327603358&amp;rnid=1000">
            <span class="refinementLink">Health, Fitness & Dieting</span><span class="narrowValue">(3)</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li style="margin-left: 6px">
        <a href="/s/ref=sr_nr_n_2?rh=k%3Ahow+to+grow+tomatoes%2Cn%3A283155%2Cp_n_feature_browse-bin%3A618073011%2Cn%3A%211000%2Cn%3A6&amp;bbn=1000&amp;sort=salesrank&amp;keywords=how+to+grow+tomatoes&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1327603358&amp;rnid=1000">
            <span class="refinementLink">Cookbooks, Food & Wine</span><span class="narrowValue">(2)</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How could I do this with XPath?

the code is from the link [amazon kindle search](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_nr_p_n_feature_browse-b_mrr_2?rh=k%3ahow%20to%20grow%20tomatoes,n:283155,p_n_feature_browse-bin:618073011&bbn=283155&sort=salesrank&keywords=how%20to%20grow%20tomatoes&ie=UTF8&qid=1327603348&rnid=618072011)

currently i am trying

```
$rank=array();

$words = $xpath->query('//ul[@id="ref_1000"]/li/a/span[@class="refinementLink"]');
foreach ($words as $word) {

        $rank[]=(trim($word->nodeValue));


 }
 var_dump($rank);
```

Comment: What took are you using to parse the HTML?

Comment: i am using curl to grab the page, than using domdocument and xpath to select data..

Comment: You say you want `narrowValue` but then your code uses `refinementLink`. Which is it? Either way, my solution below should work. Just substitute the desired class name.

Comment: i want refinementLink and then narrawvalues too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following expression should work:

```
//*[@id='ref_1000']/li/a/span[@class='narrowValue']
```

For better performance you could provide a direct path to the start of this expression, but the one provided is more flexible (given that you probably need this to work across multiple pages).

Keep in mind, also, that your HTML parser might generate a different result tree than the one produced by Firebug (where I tested). Here's an even more flexible solution:

```
//*[@id='ref_1000']//span[@class='narrowValue']
```

Flexibility comes with potential performance (and accuracy) costs, but it's often the only choice when dealing with tag soup.

Comment: still showing an empty array, although updated the xpath query you provided

Comment: @NewBee - Are you sure the array is `null`? Or could it be that you shouldn't use `nodeValue` but instead something like `textContent` or `text`? I don't use PHP, so I'm not sure, but you need to verify exactly where the error is.

Comment: if I use double quotes for class values (e.g "refinementLinke"), i get an empty array, no result, and if i use single qoute as you did, i get unexptect_t string error

Comment: @NewBee - I don't know PHP, but this looks suspect: `$rank[]=(trim($word->nodeValue));` Do you *really* mean to assign to `$rank[]` or should there be some index in those brackets?

Comment: same code for $arry[] is working in my file, so i thnk its not an issue,

Comment: @lwburk: that's the standard way short php-way to push an element unto the end of the array / hashtable, which will auto-number, so not the issue at this point.

Comment: @Wrikken - Thanks. I've tested the XPath elsewhere, so I know it works. I was just fishing :)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to grap the categories names:

```
// Suppress invalid markup warnings
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

// Create SimpleXML object
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->loadHTML($html); // $html - string fetched by CURL 
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);

// Find a category nodes
$categories = $xml->xpath("//span[@class='refinementLink']");
```

#### EDIT. Using DOMDocument

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

// Select the parent node
$categories = $xpath->query("//span[@class='refinementLink']/..");

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo '<pre>';
    echo $category->childNodes->item(1)->firstChild->nodeValue; 
    echo $category->childNodes->item(2)->firstChild->nodeValue;
    echo '</pre>';
    // Crafts, Hobbies & Home (19)
}
```

Comment: thanks, can i use it without xml object? currently i am using domdocument object and then apply query to it..

Comment: using the the xpath you provide, i get the all the nodes with span class refinementlink, what i want to get is, just take out first node and it ancentors..

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\wamp\www\edwin\scrapping.php on line 217 getting this error using your code ...line 217 hold echo $category->childNodes->item(1)->firstChild->nodeValue;

Comment: You XML structure is probably a little different. But XPath expression should be fine.

Answer (score -2):

I'd highly recommend you checkout the [phpQuery library](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/). It's essentially the jQuery selectors engine for PHP, so to get at the text you're wanting you could do something like:

```
foreach (pq('span.refinementLink') as $p) {
  print $p->text() . "\n";
}
```

That should output something like:

```
Crafts, Hobbies & Home
Health, Fitness & Dieting
Cookbooks, Food & Wine
```

It's by far the easiest screen scraping, DOM parsing thing I know of for PHP.