# using xpath to extract data by introducing ancestor in xpath query

Tags: php, regex, arrays, xpath, domdocument

i am using following code

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
@$doc->loadHTML($data);
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
 //Select the parent node
$categories =$xpath->query('//span[@class="refinementLink"]/ancestor::a/li/ul');
$abcd=array();
var_dump($categories);
foreach ($categories as $category) {


    $abcd[]=$category->nodeValue; 
      print_r('<br/>'.$abcd);
    // Crafts, Hobbies & Home (19)
}` //var_dump($abcd);
```

now , what this code do? it selects a span tag, dom listing of span tag is

> ul--li(4)--a(2)--span(3)

the output is

> object(DOMNodeList)[3]

it looks like i am doing thing okay, there are 3 span tags in my html document, 
what i need is , how i can get the text of these span tag?i need the text between the span tags
any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`->textContent`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.textcontent)

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $abcd[]=$category->textContent; 
}
var_dump($abcd);
```

Comment: sorry unable to understand, looks like, i have to memorize whole list while solving this problem

Comment: That is the property you want... I was a bit lazy, I'll add in a bit ;) No need to memorize lists (I don't either), but reading through all the documentation of the object you have at hand if you want a property works well with the excellent php-documentation.

Comment: $abcd[]=$category->nodeValue->textcontent;  and  $abcd[]=$category->textcontent; i tried these replavedment, but still the same output

Comment: BTW: `object(DOMNodeList)[3]` does not mean there are 3 elements in it afaik, what does `var_dump($categories->length);` say?

Comment: int 0 is retuned by using var_dump($categories->length);

Comment: $category->textContent using C caps, still same output is given in question

Comment: NO chat for me, Im offline in 1 minute: suffice to say: your Xpath doesn't work: it doesn't find the nodes. Return to that: until you have a positive number here there are no matches (examine the HTML carefully). After that, you can use the `textContent`.

Comment: BTW: look at the output of `$doc->saveHTML()` to see exactly what DOMDocument loaded, sometimes it differs from the actual input...

Comment: thanks for the help...i reached at this point by working on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024649/extracting-node-values-using-xpath

Comment: if you can help me out, it would be nice of yuo

Comment: gr8 comment ,,$doc->saveHTML()  told me where i was stuck

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you can probably pull the @attribute at the start when you do the XPath query. Predicates in XPath handle the foreach for you.

I use XML developer from Oxygen IDE, which works pretty well to show what XPath parses out of XML so you can be more certain about what to expect.

//span/@text[../@class="refinementLink"]/ancestor::a/li/ul
I am not sure if text is your target text's attribute but in XPath, whatever right before [] is about what you want to select. You chose it to be a node, so you had to do additional work there. If you pull out a sequence of Strings instead, you might get something else. I never tried it myself, just offering an alternative thought.