# how to nest xpath queries

Tags: php, dom, xpath, nested

i am using the following nested xpath query

```
$xpath->query('//ul[@id="ref_1000"]/li[not(strong)][//span[@class="refinementLink"]]');
```

what i want is

search from ul with id ref_1000 exlcluding specifc li tag, say it STEP 1

from STEP 1, search from span with class refinementLink

Can anybody help me making this nested xpath query?

Comment: Is this still about [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024649/extracting-node-values-using-xpath)? Because [this simply works](http://pastebin.com/q2uy0CqB)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expression:

```
//ul[@id="ref_1000"]/li[not(strong)]//span[@class="refinementLink"]
```

This selects any `span` that has a `class` attribute whose string value is `refinementLink` that is a descendant of any `li` that does not have a `strong` child that is a child of the `ul` with an `id` attribute whose string value is `ref_1000`.

Comment: thanks again and again, i am trying for previous 3 days but still success is away from me..the code you provided is not working at my end, if i remove [@id=ref_1000"], it works for next ul, i have made in confirmed that ul with id=ref_1000 has span tag in it...what should i do now?

Comment: i found the reason, code you provided is okay, i was stuck somewhere else